# Как изменить при клике класс элемента

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатие на один `div` добавлялся класс у `div` на который нажал и соседние `div` с одинаковыми классами .

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  box[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var x = i; x <= i + 3; x++) {
      i++;
      box[i].classList.add('life');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: grey;
}

.life {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Измените заголовок вопроса на "Как изменить при клике класс элемента";
Оставьте 5 div'ов, этого будет достаточно;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/4zxh0fq2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function addClass(elements) {
  elements.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el) el.classList.add('life')
  })
}

var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
boxes.forEach(function(el, index) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function click() {
    var prevEl = boxes[index - 1]
    var currEl = boxes[index]
    var nextEl = boxes[index + 1]
    addClass([currEl, prevEl, nextEl])
  })
})
```

```css
.box {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: grey;
}

.life {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```